# Adobe Flash HTML - display text on front of image

Tags: html, flash, actionscript

I work with ActionScript2 and Adobe Flash CS5 11.0.2.489.
I need to have an image with text on top of it which can change and have different sizes. The image has to stretch with the size of the text (will be better if act like a slicing sprite).

With the architecture I got I would prefer if I can handle it only by htmltext.
I tried to use those kind of html:

[Backgroundimage](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp)

```
<body  background='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/wiki-mario-kart-wii/images/2/29/Koopa.png/revision/latest?cb=20150203160223&path-prefix=fr'>
   <div style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%);">Pilou</div>
</body>
```

or

[Text Over Image](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp)

```
<div style="position:relative; text-align:center; color:white;">
   <div style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%);">Pilou</div>
   <img src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/wiki-mario-kart-wii/images/2/29/Koopa.png/revision/latest?cb=20150203160223&path-prefix=fr' style='width=100%'>
</div>
```

But they didn't display my text on top of image.
Have you some idea on how solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same structure. Create a container MovieClip, then attach to it another MovieClip that will hold the loaded image. Then create text filed inside the said container.
I might be wrong (I ditched AS2 long ago), but when creating new stuff in AS2 you specify place where it is created and level at which it is attached to. Just keep the text above the image.
Also, when the image is loaded set the MC width to the text width and then set _scale to _scaley.

Comment: Thank's,  but the problem it's I cannot modify my flash file I just have a textfield wich get an html line. So all the logic have to come from the html line :/

Comment: htmlText is very limited. You won't get such 'advanced' structures to work in it. You can either find a way to modify the flash file or by showing an actual image with text overlay in it.